# Is there a function that does the same thing as an INNER JOIN in MicroStrategy?

Tags: microstrategy

MicroStrategy-I need to do an INNER JOIN starting from the IF condition of an attribute that I created. I need to prioritize the true condition of the if when the same id repeats itself and ends up fulfilling both conditions of the if.

Comment: Can you add more detail about this?